# How to iterate array of Observable<boolean> and break when an Observable emits certain value?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I now have a type:

```
export interface IClickHandler {
  index: number; // call order starting from 0
  handleClick$(event: any): Observable<boolean>;
}
```

Before the handleClick$ looked like this:

```
handleClick(event: any): boolean;
```

So in each handler I created a new method handleClick$ that calls the old handleClick:

```
  public handleClick$(evt: any): Observable<boolean> {
    return new Observable(subscriber => {
      const isHandled = this.handleClick(evt);
      subscriber.next(isHandled);
      subscriber.complete();
    });
  }
```

in my component i have an array-field and a method seen below:

```
private handlers: IClickHandler[] = [];
```

I had method that executed each handler.handleClick until one returns true.

```
  public handleControlClick(event: any) {
    // these are ordered in array to ensure call order
    for (const handler of this.handlers) {
      if (handler.handleClick(event)) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

And now I need to adapt it to:

```
boolean -> Observable<boolean>
```

change. How this is done?

Comment: When you use Observables you are using streams of events. In this case, you would have an array of streams of events, with events probably representing the clicks of buttons according to the names. So, what do you want to achieve with such streams? In other words what should happen when you click button 1 or button 2 or button n?

Comment: This is general issue and the issue has nothing to do with clicks per se. I need the code of the current handler in iteration to be executed so it must be subscribed somehow. But IF the handler emits true the next handler's code should not be executed. Each handleClick$ emits only 1 value and completes.

Comment: So, if I understand right, you want to execute only the subscription of the first handler/observable that emits. Once one handler/observable emits, all the other subscription have to be terminated. Right?

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating an array of all your observables, and then using [`merge`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/merge), you will get an observable that emits whenever each individual observable emits a value, and using [`takeWhile`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/takeWhile) with your condition to unsubscribe once it becomes false, something like this

```js
import { takeWhile, interval, tap, merge } from 'rxjs';

const s1 = interval(1000);
const s2 = interval(2000);
const s3 = interval(3000);

const arr = [s1, s2, s3];
const stoppingValue = 7;

const c = merge(...arr).pipe(
  tap((value) => console.log(value)),
  takeWhile((value) => value !== stoppingValue),
).subscribe();
```

Comment: This seems to work when the observables are really fast, but if I add pipe(delay(1000) to 1st Observable in array the code in 2nd handler is called even though 1st has not emitted

Comment: This seems to work when the observables are really fast, but if I add pipe(delay(1000) to 1st Observable in array the code in 2nd handler is called even though 1st has not emitted. This works if you replace merge with concat.

Comment: If you want all your observers to emit their value first before checking on condition, you can `zip` just instead of `merge`.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/zip

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to leverage [`concat`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat) and [`every`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/conditional/every) in combination to concatenate your observables and shortcircuit if one of the conditions fails (in this case if one of the obsevables returns `true`):

**Setup**

```
const handlerObjects: IClickHandler[] = [
  {
    index: 0,
    handleClick$: of(false)
  },
  {
    index: 1,
    handleClick$: of(false)
  },
  {
    index: 2,
    handleClick$: of(true)
  },
  {
    index: 3,
    handleClick$: of(false)
  },
];
```

**Logic**

```
const handlers: Observable<boolean>[] =
  handlerObjects
    .map(
      (handlerObject, index) => handlerObject.handleClick$
         // Unnecessary pipe, just for index tracking
         .pipe(tap(() => {console.log(`${index} called`)
    );

const concatHandlers$: Observable<boolean> = concat(...handlers).pipe(every((value) => !value))

concatHandlers$.subscribe();

// 0 called
// 1 called
// 2 called

// Note: 3 not called due to shortcircuit on the 3rd item returning true
```

Comment: I tried @fujy's approach and took your concat and that seems to work (unlike merge that was proposed). Maybe your solution works as well.

Answer (score 0):

I read from the comment

> I want 1st observable to emit then if the emitted value is false, the
> next one until some emits true. Then the rest are skipped.

So, I understand that you want to run all handlers one Observable emits `false`, after which no other handler has to be executed.

If this understanding is right, then one way could be the following

```
// create an Observable which is the merge of all Observables
// use share to make sure that the derived Observables all share the same
// upstream
const mergedObs$ = merge(...arr).pipe(share());

// stop$ emits when the first value is true and then completes since we have take(1)
const stop$ = mergedObs$.pipe(
  filter((isTrue) => isTrue),
  take(1)
);

// the final Observable emits until stop$ emits
mergedObs$
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(stop$)
  )
  .subscribe((value) => console.log(value));
```

Comment: No: I want 1st observable to emit then if the emitted value is false, the next one until some emits true. Then the rest are skipped.